# No history property in react app when building protected routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using [this approach](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/49/Create-a-ProtectedRoute-for-Logged-In-Users-with-Route-Redirect-and-a-Render-Prop-in-React-Router) to make some routes in my application only accessible after log in.

So in App.js I have some `ProtectedRoute`s.

```
<ProtectedRoute path='/projects' auth={this.props} component={Projects} />
<ProtectedRoute path='/search' auth={this.props} component={Search} />
<ProtectedRoute path='/admin' auth={this.props} component={Admin} />
```

And my `ProtectedRoute` function is like this:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Comp, auth, path, ...rest }) => {
    const isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated;
    const sendprops = { ...auth, ...rest };
    return (
    
        <Route
            path={path}
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                return isAuthenticated ? (
                    <Comp {...sendprops} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to='/' />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

But having done that, I've totally broken my Search component, which relies on being able to see and push to the `history` property.

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname,
    search: `?query=${ this.state.searchQuery}&search_type=${this.state.searchType}&page=${this.state.searchPage}`
});
```

When I try to console.log out the properties in the Search component, I can see `location` still, but I've lost `history`. So in what feels like a somewhat ham fisted, ignorant fashion, I've wrapped my Search export in `withRouter`.

```
export default withRouter(Search);
```

And now I can see the `history` again. But I have no idea why I lost it in the first place? Insights would be greatly appreciated.

As requested, here is the Search component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ResultList from './SearchResultList';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'


class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
        let url_query = '';
        let url_search_type = '';
        let url_search_page = 1;
        let loading = false;

        if(this.props.location.search) {
            const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
            url_query = params.get('query');
            url_search_type = params.get('search_type');
            url_search_page = params.get('page') || 1;
            loading = true;
        }
        
        this.state = {
            searchQuery: url_query,
            searchType: url_search_type,
            searchPage: url_search_page,
            searchResult: {
                results: [],
                pages_left: '',
                pages_right: '',
                page: '',
                type: ''
            },
            isLoading: loading
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.state.isLoading){
            this.doSearch();
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const search_name = e.target.name;
        const search_value = e.target.value.trim();

        this.setState({
            [search_name]: search_value,
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname,
            search: `?query=${ this.state.searchQuery }&search_type=${this.state.searchType}&page=${this.state.searchPage}`
        });

        this.setState({
            isLoading: true,
            searchPage: 1
        }, this.doSearch);
    }

    changePage = (e) => {
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname,
            search: `?query=${ this.state.searchQuery }&search_type=${this.state.searchType}&page=${this.state.searchPage}`
        });
        
        this.setState({
            searchPage: e,
            isLoading: true
        }, this.doSearch);
    }
    
    doSearch = () => {
        //console.log(this.state);
 
        const endpoint = 'http://urlurlurllll/search?query=' + this.state.searchQuery + '&search_type=' + this.state.searchType + '&page=' + this.state.searchPage;

        //console.log(endpoint);

        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(jdata => {
                this.setState({
                    searchResult: {
                        results: jdata.results,
                        pages_left: jdata.pages_left,
                        pages_right: jdata.pages_right,
                        page: jdata.page,
                        type: this.state.searchType
                    },
                    isLoading: false
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    

    render (){
        
        const isLoading = this.state.isLoading;
        const searchResult = this.state.searchResult;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>
                    <h1>Search</h1>
                    <form>
                        <label>Search Term:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input-search" name="searchQuery" value={this.state.searchQuery} onChange={ event => this.handleChange(event) } />

                        <label>Search Type:</label>
                        <select id="select-type" name="searchType" value={this.state.searchType} onChange={ event => this.handleChange(event) }>
                            <option value=''>Select Type</option>
                            <option value='hashtag'>hashtag</option>
                            <option value='handle'>handle</option>
                            <option value='keyword'>keyword</option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="button" id="btn-search" onClick={event => this.handleSubmit(event)}>Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div>
                    { isLoading ? (
                        <div>
                            <p>Loading...</p>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <h2>Search Results</h2>
                            {searchResult.results.length ? (
                                <ResultList searchResult={searchResult} changePage={this.changePage} />
                            ) : (
                                <p>Use the little form up there to start searching!</p>
                            )}
                        
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>   
                
           
        );
    }

}

export default withRouter(Search);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you mind also sharing your `Search` component code so we can see how it is constructed, exported, etc...?

Comment: Sure, I've added it. My first react app so... try and overlook anything else I might be doing terribly please! :-p

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to see how `location` and `history` were being accessed and if you had and were mixing up named and default exports (`withRouter` HOC). `Search` looks good though. Took another deeper look at the protected route component and have a good idea as to the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

I think the issue is the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) from `render` aren't passed along to the component. (*Though it is unclear to me how the `location` route prop was still working*)

## Solution

Spread the route props (`match`, `location`, and `history`) provided from `render` into the component being rendered.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Comp, auth, path, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated;
  const sendprops = { ...auth, ...rest };
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => // <-- route props need to be
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Comp {...sendprops} {...props} /> // <-- passed to component
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

I just checked that tutorial/lesson you linked to see what they were doing and they pass the route props through as well.

[image]

Comment: Yes! I was messing with it because I couldn't seem to get it to pass some authentication related props, so instead of adding them on top of props like `{...props} {...auth}` I totally replaced it with auth, then tried to send `...rest` in hopes that it would give me the history. But `props` was what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: thank you, this solution solved my issue. I was assuming that passing {...rest}  was sufficient, didn't realise I needed to go one layer below and pass to the actual component.

Comment: @trig79 Correct, the `{ ...rest }` is only to spread the private route props through to the `Route` component, but then you need to also spread the route props through to the rendered component.